# Bootstrap columns with the same heights

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row1">
      <div class="col col1 col-md-3">
          Column 1
      </div>
      <div class="col col2 col-md-3">
          Column 2 
      </div>
      <div class="col col3 col-md-3">
          <div class="row">
              Column 3
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              Column 4
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I'm using bootstrap grid layout system and I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

The idea is that col1 and col2 should have the same height as col3 and col4 combined.

Is there a way of doing this without specifying the height of the container and setting height 100% on children elements as I did on this example?

[Jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/t1uo6mvt/4/)

Comment: “layouting” — not a word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading: [How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

You can use:

```
.row{
    overflow: hidden; 
}

[class*="col-"]{
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
```

Here's a runnable example:

```css
.row{
    overflow: hidden; 
}

[class*="col-"]{
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
}

.row1 {
  height: 100%;
}

.col1{
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
}

.col2{
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
}

.col3{
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row1">
      <div class="col col1 col-xs-3">
          Column 1
      </div>
      <div class="col col2 col-xs-3">
          Column 2 
      </div>
      <div class="col col3 col-xs-3">
          <div class="row">
              Column 3
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              Column 4
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try using display: flex like this:

```
.row-full-height {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/t1uo6mvt/7/)'s a working fiddle

```css
.col1 {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.col2 {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.col3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.row-full-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-full-height row1">
    <div class="col col1 col-md-3">
      Column 1
    </div>
    <div class="col col2 col-md-3">
      Column 2
    </div>
    <div class="col col3 col-md-3">
      <div class="row">
        Column 3
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        Column 4
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```